# Get the View Render Time in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, pagespeed

**Edit**: I ended up using [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/)

I have been watching the MVC 4 videos by Scott Allen from Pluralsight on asp.net site.
In one of modules on async he shows the view render times using sync & async on the home page.

I am working on optimizing an existing MVC 4 app and have done all that can be done that ySlow and PageSpeed suggest. The page load, that is the time when user hits the enter key after typing the url and the time it takes the full page to appear in the browser is now around 3 - 4 seconds.

The next step and also one of the suggestions is to look at the view render times.

How do I get that?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Install glimpse into your project, there are some useful timings on there. You can find it on nuget

Answer (score 0):

Found this - http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/02/httpmodule-for-timing-requests.aspx/
Hope it will help